# How can I make an icon open a hyperlink in new tab by default?

Tags: html, r-markdown, pandoc, quarto

Currently I have a Quarto Blog with some icons in the navigation menu, each of them have a hyperlink to another site, but they do not open in another tab, instead they open in the same tab as the blog.

The icons are configured inside the file `_quarto.yml`, like this:

```
  navbar:
    left:
      - icon: stack-overflow
        href: https://stackoverflow.com/users/9696037/vin%c3%adcius-f%c3%a9lix
```

I read the [documentation](https://quarto.org/docs/reference/projects/websites.html) ,
and did some research, I found methods, such as using `target = "_blank"`, but I do not know how to configure it inside quarto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Lua filter to open external links in a new tab:

```lua
function Link(link)
  if link.target:match '^https?%:' then
    link.attributes.target = '_blank'
    return link
  end
end
```

The code was shared by @tarleb on [Mastodon](https://fosstodon.org/@pandoc/109433924551943647).

The [document](https://quarto.org/docs/extensions/filters.html) on how to use Lua filters in Quarto.

Comment: Could you maybe go a bit more into detail of how to make this work? I could not figure out where to put the `.lua` file in my folder and how to get it to run even with the documentation you linked. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: When using a Pandoc Lua filter, you'll need to make sure that the .lua file is located in the same directory as the input file you're converting with Pandoc. For example, if you have a file called `input.md` that you want to convert using your Lua filter, you should place the Lua file in the same directory as `input.md`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tried adding the `.lua` file just there but I guess I need to somehow let Pandoc or in my case the quarto project know that it should use this file or not?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `target:` option within `- icon:`

```
navbar:
    left:
      - icon: stack-overflow
        href: https://stackoverflow.com/users/9696037/vin%c3%adciusf%c3%a9lix
        target: _blank
```

Quarto documentation on navigation items [here](https://quarto.org/docs/reference/projects/websites.html#nav-items).